# how to make download box

Tags: javascript, download

I want to know how to make a download box in javascript.
I want to make a set of data to a csv file and let the users be able to download this.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?
some links or some snippets of code would be nice. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to generate a file in JavaScript, and offer it to the user to download directly, without going through the server side.

This is not possible in JavaScript proper, but [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/) is a Flash helper library that does exactly that.

> Downloadify is a tiny JavaScript + Flash library that enables the generation and saving of files on the fly, in the browser, without server interaction.